# How to install PHP 5.2.4 in CentOS release 6.5 (Final)?

Tags: centos, software-installation, php

Folks I need to install PHP 5.2.4 in CentOS release 6.5 (Final). My souces list are:

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the 
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6


# CentOS-Vault.repo
#
# CentOS Vault holds packages from previous releases within the same CentOS Version
# these are packages obsoleted by the current release and should usually not 
# be used in production
#-----------------

[C6.0-base]
name=CentOS-6.0 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.0/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.0-updates]
name=CentOS-6.0 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.0/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.0-extras]
name=CentOS-6.0 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.0/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.0-contrib]
name=CentOS-6.0 - Contrib
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.0/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.0-centosplus]
name=CentOS-6.0 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.0/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0
#-----------------

[C6.1-base]
name=CentOS-6.1 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.1/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.1-updates]
name=CentOS-6.1 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.1/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.1-extras]
name=CentOS-6.1 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.1/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.1-contrib]
name=CentOS-6.1 - Contrib
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.1/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.1-centosplus]
name=CentOS-6.1 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.1/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0
#-----------------

[C6.2-base]
name=CentOS-6.2 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.2/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.2-updates]
name=CentOS-6.2 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.2/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.2-extras]
name=CentOS-6.2 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.2/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.2-contrib]
name=CentOS-6.2 - Contrib
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.2/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.2-centosplus]
name=CentOS-6.2 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.2/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0
#-----------------

[C6.3-base]
name=CentOS-6.3 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.3/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.3-updates]
name=CentOS-6.3 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.3/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.3-extras]
name=CentOS-6.3 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.3/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.3-contrib]
name=CentOS-6.3 - Contrib
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.3/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.3-centosplus]
name=CentOS-6.3 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.3/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0
#-----------------

[C6.4-base]
name=CentOS-6.4 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.4/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.4-updates]
name=CentOS-6.4 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.4/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.4-extras]
name=CentOS-6.4 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.4/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.4-contrib]
name=CentOS-6.4 - Contrib
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.4/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0

[C6.4-centosplus]
name=CentOS-6.4 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.4/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
enabled=0
```

I've tried the following procedures:

http://gaganonthenet.com/2012/07/17/downgrade-package-using-yum/

http://www.curvve.com/blog/servers/2013/safely-downgrade-php-5-4-5-3-centos-linux-plesk-nucleus/#.UqYSaVUnd4Y

With no luck! What am I missing? I cannot find the package version I need.

Comment: CentOS6/RHEL6 6.0 shipped with PHP 5.3, there is no older release.  EL5 shipped with 5.1 with a php53 set of alternate packages.  Why do you need that specific release?

Comment: @jsbillings I need to install a home made application in a production environment. The only PHP version where the application is assured to work is 5.2.4 at the momment the application dies without any warnings.

Comment: I suspect that this application was probably targeting some other distro other than CentOS.  Perhaps you'd be better off using whatever it was intended to run on.  Otherwise, you'll have to spend some development time porting it to 5.3.

Comment: @jsbillings the application is sort of abandononware an not well documented peice of software. Also CentOS is the distro of our production environments so in this case Ive no option. I'm by no means lecturing you just explaining my situation :(

Comment: @jsbillings say you're testing something like anything wrote for wordpress. Wordpress supports up to 5.2 (even though PHP doesn't even support 5.2 anymore) so you need a jenkins server with 5.2 but you dont really give a damn about everything else so you would just want to use the latest centos with PHP 5.2